# Mysql, insert if not duplicate else replace - for an entire table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `t1` and `t2`, I'd like to update `t1` with the content of `t2` on the condition that if `t1` and `t2` share the same unique key on a given row, then `t2` is used and overwrites the `t1` row, otherwise we add the non-duplicate `t2` rows to `t1`.

So in short add columns from `t2` to `t1` when not duplicate, else, overwrite `t1` with `t2` duplicate rows.

I know MySQL has multiple approaches to doing this, but none appear to achieve merging over the entire table without having to explicitly list all columns to be replaced.

Both `t1` and `t2` have a lot of columns in my schema, so I'd rather not list them all out.

The approach I would adopt if I didn't have as many columns is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO t1(a, b, c)
SELECT d, e, f FROM t2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b = t2.e, c = t2.f;
```

Fine for 3 columns, but I have 18 of them!

Adapting the above to achieve a more general solution which doesn't require me to be explicit as to which columns to apply the changes to is my objective.

I have got as far as:

```
insert into t1
select * from t2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    t1.b = t2.b,
    t1.c = t2.c;
```

But as seen above, I am still required to be explicit as to which columns to update when duplicates are found using the UPDATE keyword.

I'm sure there is an obvious way to avoid the issue of explicitly defining the columns to replace, but MySQL isn't my strongest language to say the least, so I'd appreciate an expert telling me how to solve this.

***Update***

I am forced to using MySQL 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need simple [REPLACE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html):

```
REPLACE INTO t1
TABLE t2
```

Of course, the tables must have the same structure (including field names, types, order...).

If not, or if you use MySQL version more ancient then 8, then use REPLACE..SELECT:

```
REPLACE INTO t1(a, b, c)
SELECT d, e, f FROM t2
```

Comment: Thanks, just to be clear, t1 won't lose any of its rows, only have some overwritten where duplicates exist between t1 and t2, and have more rows added on account of new ones from t2, is that right?

Comment: @SingleEntity *REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.* You can read this yourself if you open provided link.

Comment: Actually, having tried it, I'm finding your first example results in a syntax error for me, tested using MySQL workbench SQL 5.x

Comment: @SingleEntity You have not specified your version, so the solution for actual version is safe. Yes, 5+ does not support `TABLE`, use `REPLACE..SELECT` instead.